# How to customize checkout page by country with Shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

[image]I am trying to customize checkout page according to country for my store Can you please help.
I am trying to using following code:

```html
{% if localization.country.iso_code == 'FR' %}
Yeyi French
{% else %}
English
{% endif %}
```

but on checkout it keep showing English even I have tried to change the location through VPN.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `localization.country` returns the country of the storefront, not the user location. Shopify does not give any tool or API that would enable you to detect user's location. You need to use an external geolocation service for that, ideally with a custom app acting as middleware to protect private keys. You might also try looking for an app in Shopify Store but it's unlikely that as of 09.2022 you will find anything that would help you to solve that particular problem.

Comment: thanks for help, I have customize the checkout in French language. :) I have found some article and solved.

Comment: @ApoorvaSingh can you share your solution for readers that will find that question in google? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just want to mention that {localization} isn't available on the Order statu page.

In that text box, you are able to use the {shop} Liquid object, the {order} Liquid object, and the OrderStatus JavaScript asset.

So my approach is to use shop.locale (it is based on selected language in the store)

But if somene know how to manage it in other way, it would be great

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).